# Magento2 deployment CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, magento2

Hi I had installed magento2 with sample data.
I would deploy static css/JS but the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it return 0 error but the problem still here.
Also I can't find `deploy.php` file in the standard dir.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of error you get after clicking php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy? Are you running your project on Linux or Ubuntu?

Comment: `deploy.php` was used in magento1, which has been removed in magento2 so that commands are consistent with Symfony's CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below command for import sample data 
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

 php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

You have written

> "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it"

but it should be

> "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

or

> "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy language_code"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to deploy pub/static contents: -

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US es_ES

en_US and es_ES are the language directory.